# "Self-organizing" Team vs HR and Management

Tags: scrum, scrum-master

If a shop is small, where does self-organizing come into play. If there is only one DB Admin, one DevOps Unix Admin etc...where the manager already decided what resources are required by the company.

I see the IT manager or director already deciding what is required for particular projects in an organization, putting in the requisitions for headcount, long before scrum is in play (before even a scrum master). Does scrum come into play during hiring when the team is being recruited? i.e. Catch-22. Does it say anything about before the team exists?

Comment: What on earth is a "DevOps Unix Admin" supposed to be? DevOps is a set of processes/principles around how one does integration and deployment. It's not a job title.

Comment: would https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ be better for this?

Comment: The root of this question does not seem to be A vs B. It seems to be "Given B, how can A happen?" I think this question is salvageable if we focus on the Scrum aspect more in the context of a small team where tech skills are already tightly segregated.

Comment: Maybe a change in the question title? Something like "How can a small Scrum team be 'self organizing' when tech skills are highly segregated"' or something like that.

Comment: @GregBurghardt - correct. if there is not a large pool of skills to pull from.

Answer (score 3):

The self-organization of a team only comes into play after a team has been formed.

A manager might see that a project/product needs a DB Admin, a Unix SysAdmin and a Developer and puts together a team consisting of 3 people with those backgrounds.

The self-organization of the team comes from the fact that the team members themselves decide who will pick up which task in order to deliver in the most efficient way. Within this team, it seems fairly natural that the DB Admin will take up the database-related tasks, but who will be his backup if there are too many database tasks or he is off? For a self-organizing team, the team itself will appoint someone, rather than bothering the manager or failing to deliver.

Comment: `The self-organization of a team only comes into play after a team has been formed.` This is what I believed, but I read elsewhere otherwise. However, It was pointed out that during a sprint, the team may notice it is deficient in a resource, say Front-end UI skills, with a small siloed team.  i.e. Before scrum cycle starts, there is already heavy analysis required outside the confines of scrum.

Comment: @paulj: I don't really understand your comment. To get an idea what type of knowledge is needed for a project/product does not take a really deep analysis of the requirements. And if it is found that an error is made in the team composition, this will be found out quite early.